# Error in mysql connectivity with netbeans while creating database?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, netbeans

i am using xampp.i want to connect mysql with netbeans.i tested my connection while creating new connection from database in services tab.i get the connection successful message.but while trying to create a database i get this error

```
access denied for user"@'localhost' to database 'student'
```

Comment: sounds like a permissions issue. do you have create permissions?

Comment: how can i create permissions or edit them?

Comment: what kind of database is it? sqllite?

Comment: if it's sqllite you have to go into the database and update them aswell as updating the sqllite file

Comment: mysql database.is there something i did not know about this types?if yes please help.

Comment: i posted an answer for mysql

Answer (score 2, accepted):

for mysql

1. Revoke privileges

   ```
   revoke all privileges on *.* from 'student'@'localhost';
   ```
2. Then grant the appropriate privileges as desired:

   ```
   grant SELECT,INSERT,UPDATE,DELETE ON `db`.* TO 'student'@'localhost';
   ```

in your case you may want

```
     GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO  'student@localhost';
```

Finally, flush:

```
    flush privileges;
```

Comment: i cant create a database and what should i be specifying in `db`.* ?

Comment: Grant all should work for creating db - the second one - don't specify a database if you have *.* it'll grant you privileges on everything

Comment: I got it.After executing grant i got a message as "query ok.0 rows affected".Is that ok?

Comment: you might have to start again i.e. revoke, grant and flush

Comment: Thanks a lot!in cmd if i execute the command create database it is successful.but in netbeans i still cant create a new database by right clicking on the mysql Server @ localhost.the same access denied error is shown?

Comment: you probably have to give permissions to Server@localhost aswell

Comment: select user,host from mysql.user; to list users

Comment: i have some more doubts too.that day i tried this and got a successful message.but now even though i give the right password,connection is not established saying"access denied(using password:yes).